# Let $X$ be a set and $Y$ a topological space. What is the topology on $X$ induced by constant maps $f:X \to Y$?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a set and $Y$ a topological space. What is the topology on $X$ induced by constant maps $f:X \to Y$?

The induced topology is $\tau_X = \{f^{-1}[V] : V \in \tau_Y\}$ and $f^{-1}[V] = \{x \in X : f(x) \in V \}$

So if $f(x ) = c(x)$, then I initially considered that $f^{-1}[V]$ would be just the singletons $\{x\}$, but I don’t see why there couldn’t be a open set where the there could be multiple $f(x) \in V$ and thus the preimage wouldn’t be just the singleton?

Answer (score 1):

The inverse image of any set under a constant map is either empty or $X$. So the topology induced by constant maps is the indiscrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\tau_X = \{f^{-1}[O] \mid O \in \tau_Y\}$ by definition.

If $f$ is constant with value $y_0 \in Y$ then (recall that $f^{-1}[O]=\{x\in X\mid f(x) \in O\}$):

- $y_0 \in O \implies f^{-1}[O] = X$.
- $y_0 \notin O \implies f^{-1}[O]=\emptyset$.
- It follows that $\tau_X = \{\emptyset,X\}$, the indiscrete (or trivial) topology.

Which makes sense as the induced topology is the smallest topology that makes $f$ continuous and *all* topologies make a constant map continuous, so we just get the minimal topology on $X$.

Comment: Not sure I entirely follow, how does $y_0 \in O \implies f^{-1}[O] = X$ and $y_0 \notin O \implies f^{-1}[O] = \emptyset$?

Comment: @Wondera If $y_0 \in O$ then $x \in f^{-1}[O]$ iff $y_0 = f(x) \in O$ by definition and so this is true for all $x$ etc.